# NPM Request not get html from thai url. (Web Scraping)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, ascii, npm-request

This code will not show html in console it show error

```
var request = require('request');
var thai_url = "http://pantip.com/tag/Honda_(มอเตอร์ไซค์)";

request(thai_url, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(html);
        } else {
            console.log("Error");
        }
});
```

But I change thai_url from มอเตอร์ไซค์ to %E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%AD%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%8C%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%8B%E0%B8%84%E0%B9%8C

Like This

```
var request = require('request');

var thai_url = "http://pantip.com/tag/Honda_(%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%AD%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%8C%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%8B%E0%B8%84%E0%B9%8C)";

request(thai_url, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(html);
        } else {
            console.log("Error");
        }
});
```

The second code working right. Can I change มอเตอไซค์ to %E0%B8%A1%E0%B8...(more)? Or If it's possible, How am I doing for [http://pantip.com/tag/Honda_(มอเตอร์ไซค์)](http://pantip.com/tag/Honda_(%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%AD%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%8C%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%8B%E0%B8%84%E0%B9%8C)) working with npm request ? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. Now I can solve this problem by this

```
var thai_url = encodeURI("http://pantip.com/tag/Honda_(มอเตอร์ไซค์)");
```

Use encodeURI. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm

Answer (score 0):

First one is working fine. Just log the error instead of "error" string.

Make sure your IDE supports utf character. otherwise on saving it might be changing it. That why you might get error.

Comment: I use Netbean. I change console.log("Error"); to console.log(error); . It show null. I open this file with notepad++ & notepad. it use utf-8 encode for this file.

Comment: Actually i tried with Webstrom and it prints HTML. So no problem in the code.